# Robocopy not creating a logfile

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Can anyone show me the syntax error I've made?

```
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\desktop\" "$Destination\desktop" *.* /copy:DAT /log:"C:\Logs"
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\pictures" "$Destination\pictures" *.* /copy:DAT /log+:"C:\Logs"
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\documents\" "$Destination\documents" *.* /copy:DAT /log+:"C:\Logs"
```

Comment: Robocopy is trying to create a *file* named `c:\logs` for your log. If there's already a directory by that same name (did you create one, to hold the log files you're trying to create?), it's going to fail.

Comment: @alroc i've tried with and without but i cant manage to get it running im loosing my mind :(

Comment: With and without *what*?

Comment: Update your command with a named log file eg: `/log:"C:\Logs\robocopy.log"`

Comment: @JamesC.thanks you gave me the answer

Comment: @Valentino - actually alroc did. James made it easier.

Answer (score 1):

As alroc mentioned, it looks like `C:\Logs` is a **folder** and robocopy expects a log **file** for the `/log:` parameter.

You will need to update your command with a named log file eg: `/log:"C:\Logs\robocopy.log"`